# Can you call a form object using data contained in a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For a project on which I am currently working, I need to be able to call on a variable whose name (or partial name) I have stored within a string variable.

For example, if `string s = "1"`, how would I do the following without the `if` statements?

```
if(s == "1") {
    textBox1.Visible = false;
}
if(s == "2") {
    textBox2.Visible = false;
}
```

With only two text boxes, the `if` statements aren't much of a problem, but I'd like to not have too many if I can avoid it.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more surrounding context with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping between keys and values using the class `Dictionary`. If you're trying to map integer keys into TextBox instances, an instance of `Dictionary<int, TextBox>` will do that nicely.

```
Dictionary<int, TextBox> dic = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>();
dic.Add(1, textBox1);
dic.Add(2, textBox2);
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (dic.ContainsKey(input))
   Console.WriteLine(dic[input].Text);
else
   Console.WriteLine("No box found!");
```

Comment: Or, since the keys are ints, you could just use an array....

Comment: @adv12: small non-negative ints (which they appear to be)

Comment: @BenVoigt, good qualification

Comment: @adv12, an array has the problem of being 0 indexed, but yes that could work as well. This solution is a bit safer than just searching though.

Comment: Even using small non-negative ints, the index 0 would be inconsistent with the application.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using an array and leaving null in any unwanted locations, like 0

Comment: `foreach(TextBox q in array) Console.WriteLine(q.Text);`. Some things do stop you from using null in unwanted locations. Inconsistencies produces bugs often, nothing stops you from avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't. But yes you could do the following:

```
Control userSelectedControl = Controls.Find("textBox" + space.ToString()).First();
```

This code is assumed to be run from the 'Form' object itself.

Note that this breaks if your naming scheme changes (among many other potential problems). There is probably a better approach, but without more info its hard to say what it is.

"Find" for a control collection on MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: With that, I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"

Comment: Thats what I get for not actually clicking the link for "Find" on MSDN. Just use the 0 index or .First(). Sorry for the mistake.